# Why does buying Treasury bonds on the secondary market make it easier to sell Treasury bonds at a later date?

Tags: united-states, investing, bonds, treasury

I [read](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/08/treasuries-fed.asp#:%7E:text=trickier%20to%20trade.-,When%20you%20buy%20bonds%20on%20the%20secondary%20market%20through%20a,bonds%20at%20a%20later%20date):

> Buying on the secondary market also makes it easier to sell Treasury bonds at a later date.

Why does buying Treasury bonds on the secondary market make it easier to sell Treasury bonds at a later date?

Comment: The same way holding stocks in street name makes it easier than having paper certificates in a safe deposit box.

Answer (score 3):

Because you've already established access to the market.